# How to find all occurrence of a function in a package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function, package

Say I want to print out all the functions (or methods) in Numpy that at least calls the `numpy.lib.utils.who` function once. What I expect is a list of strings that looks like this:

```
['numpy.ndarray.flatten', 'numpy.ma.MaskedArray.recordmask', 'numpy.reshape']
```

(just for an example, doesn't mean they actually call the `numpy.lib.utils.who` function)

Is there any way to do this efficiently?

Comment: Depending on how the functions are referenced that could be very tricky. Pragmatically I have no clue, but if it is a one off question I would probably open the source in an IDE like PyCharm and use that to find callers.